# Change Git remote repository password

Tags: git, ssh, passwords, vps

I've got a Git remote repo installed on a VPS. All the (physical) users of this git use the same user/password, and I would like to change the password.

In order to clone the git repository we use ssh like that :
- `git clone -v "ssh://myuser@my.adresse.ip/my/user/my-project"` then I type the password associated with `myuser`

How can I change that password ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no password for git, as git doesn't handle authentification.

If you need to change your server user's password, just issue theses commands:

```
ssh myuser@my.adresse.ip
passwd
```

It is recommanded to have a either a very strong password or using a key-based authentification, since this will be subject to bruteforce as every public ssh server.